# What is the right site to ask about existing Game Boy replicas?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I want to know which Game Boy replicas currently exist that can read real Game Boy cartridges.
My question got closed on [retrocomputing](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/25135/are-there-other-game-boy-replicas-than-the-analogue-pocket-that-can-run-game-boy) because of being off-topic.
What is the correct site to ask this?

Comment: You could check "Arqade" or "Hardware recommendations". Be sure to check their //help/on-topic though.

Comment: On second thought, this is explicitly off-topic on Arqade: *"Recommendations for software, hardware, games, or genres... "*

Comment: @Luuklag It's possible this could be phrased as a non-recommendation question, since OP is simply looking for hardward that exists, rather than the "best" or "recommended" option– definitely worth an ask on Arqade's meta though since it's for sure an edge case.

Comment: Yes this is true. I am asking for the existance and not for a recommandation.

Comment: As an Arqade moderator, I've been trying to determine a definitive answer on this type of question.  I feel its a grey area for Arqade.  I believe in the past when similar questions of this nature get asked, they are often poorly received/closed.  I can't really find an example to go off of at the moment.  I encourage you to ask on the [Arqade Meta site](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/) about this to see what the community thinks.

Answer (score 2):

Your question was reopened on [Retrocomputing](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/25135/are-there-other-game-boy-replicas-than-the-analogue-pocket-that-can-run-game-boy), and you have received a good answer to it. As pointed out in a [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/308065/wizzwizz4) by a moderator of that site, the reason for its initial closure was because the question is asking for a list of devices.

Recommendation questions, and those that ask for lists, are generally off-topic on sites on the network. This also applies to [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

And while your question is indeed not so much asking for a recommendation as it is asking for the mere existence of replicas, I fear this [technicality](https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1147/is-asking-for-the-existence-of-a-device-equal-to-a-buying-recommendation) might be overlooked or ignored on most platforms where the subject matter would be on-topic.

However, **[Hardware Recommendations](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com) seems [a perfect fit](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for your query**:

> In general your question should be:
>
> - a request for a product recommendation
> - a request for information that will lead to a product decision

You should possibly add a few more details to accommodate the second bullet point.
The type of hardware, i.c. a hand-held gaming device, should also be on-topic, as far as I can tell (see [here](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/266) and [here](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/81)).

Comment: The question _was_ closed on Retrocomputing; however, it has since been re-opened. It was closed more for being a list question than for being off-topic; and that passage of `/help/on-topic` isn't supposed to claim that questions about modern emulation devices are off-topic. They are on-topic as they relate to the retro stuff. (Repair questions for modern computers would be off-topic, even if they're used as emulators, but that's a different matter.)

Comment: @wizzwizz4 I added in that information, thank you.